# Deallocating memory in array C++ , XCode

Tags: c++

I'm quite new one in the field of C++ development. I need to deallocate memory in array. But the problem occurs. Memory doesn't seem to be free after this piece of code.

```
double** matrix = new double*[str];
for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
     matrix[i] = new double[col];


for(int j=0; j<str; j++)
     delete[] matrix[j];
delete [] matrix;
```

I'm using Xcode and believing it, Memory doesn't zero after ending of the program. I don't understand why. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: it most probably does. or if it doesn't, then only because of some debugging/instrumentation magic. try running your program in the command line and monitor it using Valgrind – you'll see no leaks related to this piece of code.

Comment: BTW, if you "need to dellocate memory in array", by which I assume you meant "allocate", then you better just use `std::vector`.

Comment: "Memory doesn't zero after ending of the program." this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant after using that piece of code in the end of program i had't something close to zero in the memory use. as far as i understand i should have had. how i must rewrite the code to free memory?

Comment: Freeing does not imply zeroing of the memory previously allocated.